# How to decorate all similar methods in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Here is my class:

```
class Book
  def read
     # something
  end
end
```

And another one:

```
class Magazine
  def read
     # something
  end
end
```

Now, I want to decorate both `read` methods in these two classes. I want them both to print "hello" right before they start working. How do I do that? I suspect, I need to use mixins, but can't figure out exactly how.

Comment: Ah, it's a pity that your bot is not giving out rewards here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `prepend` module:

```
module Decorator
  def read
    puts "hello"
    super
  end
end

class Book
  prepend Decorator

  def read
    puts "bye"
  end
end

class Magazine
  prepend Decorator

  def read
    puts "cya"
  end
end

Book.new.read 
# "hello"
# "bye"

Magazine.new.read
# "hello"
# "cya"
```

As well there is more clean way to do this kind of modifications with `refinements`:

```
class Book
  def read
    puts "bye"
  end
end

class Magazine
  def read
    puts "cya"
  end
end

module Decorator
  def read
    puts "hello"
    super
  end
end

module DecoratedBook
  refine Book do
    prepend Decorator
  end
end

module DecoratedMagazine
  refine Magazine do
    prepend Decorator
  end
end

using DecoratedBook
using DecoratedMagazine

Book.new.read 
# "hello"
# "bye"

Magazine.new.read
# "hello"
# "cya"
```

Notice: this code may not run in `irb`.

Also you can do it right in the runtime:

```
module Decorator
  def read
    puts "hello"
    super
  end
end

[Book, Magazine].each do |klass|
  klass.prepend Decorator
end

Book.new.read 
# "hello"
# "bye"

Magazine.new.read
# "hello"
# "cya"
```

Comment: You probably want to call `super` in that decorator

Comment: You're right. I've got the original question wrong before. Thank you.

Comment: Also why class_eval? Can simply do `klass.prepend Decorator`

Comment: This is stale part of code from my previous version of answer, that I've just fixed. Generally you're totally right again. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

May be you want something as:

```
class ReaderDecorator
  def initialize(obj)
    @obj = obj
  end

  def read
    puts 'Hello'
    @obj.read
  end
end

ReaderDecorator.new(Book.new).read
ReaderDecorator.new(Magazine.new).read
```

Comment: I think this is the correct example of "decorator pattern".

Comment: @KimmoLehto: depends. For one thing, other methods are not proxied here (original object's API, if it were specified, is not reflected fully). And some clients may do type checks, so you might want your decorated object still __be_a?__  the same type.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes, with `class ReaderDecorator < SimpleDelegator` it would be better. The question does have the keyword "decorate", so an answer with an actual "decorator" is fitting.

Comment: @KimmoLehto "actual" as in "as described by gang of four"? Their decorator implements the interface (maintains both api surface and type checks). Anyway, what I was trying to say is there are flavors of decorators. Who's to say which one of them is the "real" one? :)